# WPF VB.NET how to instanciate a pack icon

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

I'm currently building an applications launcher in WPF using Mahapps.Metro iconpacks and VB.NET (not my choice). The applications list comes from a database and is retrieved when the user is connected. The buttons are build through this method:

```
Imports MahApps.Metro.IconPacks
For Each app As UserDLL.BO.UserApplication In _user.applications
   Dim btn As New MyApplicationButton(app.ApplicationName, app.ApplicationPath, app.ApplicationArgs, app.ApplicationIcon)
   btn.Content = app.ApplicationName
   btn.Style = _style
   Dim packIconMaterial As PackIconModern()
   AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf launchApp
   Apps.Children.Add(btn)
Next
```

But I have an error on `Dim packIconMaterial As PackIconModern()` it says `PackIconModern is ambiguous in the namespace 'Mahapps.Metro.IconPacks'`

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know the [fully qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces) of the `PackIconModern`? Use fully qualified name to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: The intellisense gives me Mahapps.Metro.Iconspack as the namespace that contains the different icons packs. I keep digging

Comment: I found this on stackoverflow but it's in C# and no explanation about the namespace used
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117096/assign-mahapps-metroiconpacks-to-button-in-code-behind)

Comment: Did you try: `Dim packIconMaterial As MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconModern()` ?

Comment: Could it be in conflict because of this statement in the XAML

`xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"`

?

Comment: @mm8 - Yes I did try the `Dim packIconMaterial As MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIconModern()` syntax but I still got the error.

The reference is correctly set in my project and I checked for multiple definitions but it's ok. this is the only use of this statement in the project.

Comment: No custom class to interfere :/
How can I provide you a full repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what's happening!

I installed too many references of Mahapps.Metro package in my project.
So I had in my references:

```
Mahapps.Metro
Mahapps.Metro.iconsPack
Mahapps.Metro.IconsPack.SimpleIcons
Mahapps.Metro.IconsPack.SomeOtherIconsPacks
```

Once I deleted the **Mahapps.Metro** and **Mahapps.Metro.iconsPack**, the error disappeared.

Thanks all for your help!